# how to restrict user to access a particular category in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I created a website for online shopping and i want to give my admin panel to some vendors so that they insert their own products related with a particular category they are dealing with.

For ex :- In electronics category,there are various options like cameras, mobiles etc.

```
1.So, i want one vendor who is related with mobiles should be allowed only to enter his related products(only mobiles) from admin panel.

2.And he should not be allowed to see or update the products in other categories like cameras.He will only be given access to update his related category.
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not out the box and multi-user done properly is an Enterprise Edition feature, even if you want to do it 'multi-store' instead of 'category'.

You will probably find someone has written a module to support the functionality you are after, however, what you are after goes against the overall design of Magento Community Edition.