# how to allow a new admin user to access only particular category?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to restrict user to access a particular category in magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161706/how-to-restrict-user-to-access-a-particular-category-in-magento)

i want to create a new admin user who is only allowed to access a particular category out of all the categories.

How can i do that?

Should i change in database or from admin panel.

Thanks..

Comment: actually i tried a lot ..but..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this module:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-permissions.html

Comment: is this possible to custom do this ?

Comment: yes but the amount of time to do it is probably not worth it

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel, so you access System(menu) > Permission > Role, Click on administrator and go to Role Resources on left side of screen. Set the combobox to custom. Now you can check/uncheck what you want deny the access...

Comment: hi guerra !!, i did that, but whole category is allowed to access and i want to access only a single category like electronics.